# Working with bytes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, byte

I'm developing a project in VB.NET that reads from a SERIAL PORT some info. This info comes in in a pack of 4 bytes. Im able to read the data from the serial port, but what I get is  just a pack of 4 numbers.

For example, my readings are:

```
134 0 0 4
140 0 0 6
141 0 0 5
133 0 0 8
...
```

The manual explains how to convert this numbers into usable data. Im able to do it over a paper but i dont know how to code this in VB.NET. I dont know how to work at a byte-level.

I attach a picture about the byte's meaning.
[image]

Comment: Show us what have you tried please.

Comment: i dont want to write the code for you, all i can give you is this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_bitshift_operators.htm those are all the operators for bit manupilation in vb.net with a nice little example

Comment: yeah, i dont want slaves to work for me :P. Im looking for tips and tutorials. I will check that tutorial and see if i can get something useful! thanks!

Comment: +1 @Redder,"looking for tips and tutorials", not someone giving the answer.  How refreshing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks to user x4rf41

Maybe need some fixes but its what I was looking for.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub thread_lectura_tarjeta1()

        Dim RXByte As Byte 'byte recived
        Dim RXPacket As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte) 'each reading has 4 bytes
        Dim lectura As Long = 0 'is the FINAL data
        Dim COMPort As SerialPort = ensayo.get_digitalizadores(0).get_puerto_com
        Dim chk_signo As Byte = 0

        While (True)

            lectura = 0

            Do 'each package starts with a byte > 127, because is the only byte that its first bit is 0

                RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte

            Loop Until (RXByte > 127)

            RXByte = RXByte And 127
            RXPacket.Insert(0, RXByte)

            RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte            
            RXPacket.Insert(1, RXByte)

            RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte
            chk_signo = RXByte And 8
            RXPacket.Insert(2, RXByte And 7)

            RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte
            RXPacket.Insert(3, RXByte)

            lectura = RXPacket.Item(0) + RXPacket.Item(1) * 128 + RXPacket.Item(2) * 16384

            'checking sign


            If chk_signo = 8 Then ' negative number

                lectura = (lectura Xor 131071) * -1
            End If



            Sleep(1) 'wait 1 milisecond and read again

        End While
    End Sub
```